# Process stopped but connection is "ESTABLISHED"

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, netstat

I was running a Hadoop cluster on several machines with `start-all.sh` script. But I did something wrong so all java-processes were terminated (I checked that with `jps`, on every machine it returns nothing but itself). Surprisingly, executing `netstat` on the master machine shows me that there are connections with slaves in ESTABLISHED state. And now I am not able to run Hadoop again because its ports already in use.

I've found a way to manualy close these connections with `tcpkill`. But now I wonder how can this be possible? How can terminated process still use a TCP port?

Comment: If you run netstat with the -p option, it'll show you the process name using a portn. Which process is using it ?

Comment: Did you find anything in the logs?

Comment: It isn't possible. You've missed a process to kill.